# typecast with class function

Tags: delphi, casting

i want typecast using with class functions.
i have base (TBase),derived (TDer) and typecasting (TMyType) class.

Ver : Delphi 7

```delphi
TBase = class;
TDer = class;
TMyType = class;

TBase = class
  function Say : String;
  class function MYType:TMyType;
end;

TDer = class(TBase)
  a: string;
  b: string;
  function Say2 : String;
end;

TMyType=class(TBase)
  class function AsDer:TDer;
end;

{ TBase }

class function TBase.MYType: TMyType;
begin
  Result:=TMyType(Self);
end;

function TBase.Say: String;
begin
   Result:='TBase';
end;

{ TDer }

function TDer.Say2: String;
begin
  Result:='TDer';
end;

{ TMyType }

class function TMyType.AsDer: TDer;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(Self));
  Result := TDer(Self) ;
end;
```

Sample usage is below, it's calls method but when set/get field's raise error.

```delphi
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  b,c:TBase;
begin
  b:=TDer.Create;
  c:=b.MYType.AsDer;

  ShowMessage(b.MYType.AsDer.Say2); // OK. Running      
  if (@b<>@c) then ShowMessage('Not Equal');  // Shows message, Why ?
  b.MYType.AsDer.a:='hey'; // Error

  FreeAndNil(b);
end;
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fundamental problem is here:

```
class function TBase.MYType: TMyType;
begin
  Result:=TMyType(Self);
end;
```

This is a class method and so `Self` refers to a *class* and not an *instance*. Casting it to be an instance does not make it so. Exactly the same error is made in your `AsDer` class function.

Looking into the specifics, the call to

```
b.MYType.AsDer.Say2
```

is benign and appears to work fine because it does not refer to `Self`. You could equally write `TDer(nil).Say2` and that code would also work without problem. Now, if the function `Say2` referred to `Self`, that is referred to an instance, then there would be a runtime error.

```
@b<>@c
```

always evaluates to true because you are comparing the locations of two distinct local variables.

```
b.MYType.AsDer.a
```

is a runtime error because `AsDer` does not return an instance of `TDer`. So when you attempt to write to `a` you have a runtime error. This is because you are referring to `Self` and that's why this code fails, but the earlier call to `Say2` does not.

---

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here, but it looks all wrong. Even if you were working with instance methods rather than class methods, it would simply be wrong to case a base class instance to a derived class instance. If something is the wrong type, no amount of casting will turn it into the right type.

Furthermore, you should never write code that has a method of `TBase` assuming it is of type `TDerived`. The base class should know absolutely nothing of its derived classes. That is one of the very basic tenets of OOP design.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited the new version :

```delphi
TBase = class;
TDer = class;
TMyType = class;

TBase = class
  MYType:TMyType;
  constructor Create;
  destructor Destroy;
  function Say : String;
end;

TDer = class(TBase)
  a: string;
  b: string;
  function Say2 : String;
end;

TMyType=class
public
  T: TObject;
  function AsDer:TDer;
end;

{ TBase }

constructor TBase.Create;
begin
  MYType:=TMYType.Create;
  MYType.T:=TObject(Self);
end;

destructor TBase.Destroy;
begin
  MYType.Free;
end;

function TBase.Say: String;
begin
  Result:='TBase';
end;

{ TDer }

function TDer.Say2: String;
begin
  Result:='TDer';
end;

{ TMyType }

function TMyType.AsDer: TDer; 
begin
  Result := TDer(T) ;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  b:TBase;
  c:TDer;
begin
  b:=TDer.Create;
  TDer(b).a:='a';
  c:=b.MYType.AsDer;

  ShowMessage('b.MYType.AsDer='+b.MYType.AsDer.a+', c.a ='+ c.a); // OK. Running
  FreeAndNil(b);
end;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i need for a special preject. user friendly type casting for programmers.

Comment: I trust this is just demo code to work out syntax. In real code you would need to do runtime type checking with the `is` and `as` operators. Instead of blindly writing `TDer(T)` you would write `T as TDer` and so raise an intelligible runtime exception in case `T` was not a `TDer`.